# How Symfony2 load translations from translations folder

Tags: php, symfony, caching, translation

I want to wrote the simple bundle, and I need to know how Symfony2 gets all translations from the `Resources/translations` of each bundle, before it will be placed into `cache/catalogue.locale.yml` I find the Translator class what generate file for cache, but how getting translations and parses into `key => value` format I dont know/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

```
Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue
```

this

```
private function doLoadCatalogue($locale)
    {
        ....
    }
```

in `Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator`

and this

```
protected function loadCatalogue($locale)
{
 ....
\$catalogue%s = new MessageCatalogue('%s', %s);
.....
 var_export($this->catalogues[$fallback]->all(), true),
...
}
```

in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator`

If you want to do a translation bundle, you can take a look at this 'JMSTranslationBundle' bundle
check this bundle

> https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle

Comment: I already found this class, but when we go to see the catalugue.locale.yml in cache we will find the there are creating new instance of message catalogue, and inside constructore loads arrays with all our translations, and I want to know how they passes to the constructor...

Comment: yes, I readede it. Its is more clear and understandable for now. Thanks man! :)